# Can cpu cache memory be inconsistent in a multi-core environment?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, system, cpu-cache

Can cpu cache memory be inconsistent in a multi-core environment?
If consistency can be broken, can changing kernel options from pre-emptive to non-preemptive help solve this problem?

Comment: Depends on architecture. The kernel flush on context switch is a no-op on systems with process id tags on virtual addresses.